# Fullscreen window behavior and workspaces

Tags: macintosh, workspace

I've just installed Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki and while I love the GUI there are a few things I need some help with, all related to the workspace / fullscreen application behavior (coming from MacOS):

1. Is there a way to automatically put a fullscreen application in a separate workspace?
2. Is there a way to have separate workspaces for each monitor? So I can switch workspaces only for the currently active monitor.
3. Finally I noticed that fullscreen applications (Like Firefox) still have their title bar above them. I was wondering if their was a way to hide this (I did some googling and found https://launchpad.net/maximus but I'm uncertain if this is the appropriate way to do this) ?

I hope that my questions are clear enough ( and not duplicates :) ), thanks in advance for anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the only thing you have to do is bind the keybinding for fullscreen (for example I bound it to command + F) once you hit this it has the same behavior as Mac. Putting the application in a separate workspace. Sadly there is no way I've been able to find to have each screen have it's own workspaces which can be switch separately.